# UiPath trigger on distributed systems

Tags: uipath

I want to use a trigger to start an automation project, that I have developed and it works on a single machine. I now want to roll that out company wide. Does each machine in the company need the robot service running on each desktop? Therefore each desktop needs a robot license?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a Robot license on each machine where you want to run your automation.